# Data sets about nutrition/diseases

Tags: data-request, medical, food, global, disease

I have to do analysis about correlation between diseases and nutrition consumption. Where I can find data sets about food (nutrition) consumption, divided by diseases (I can also use two data sets: nutrition ~ country and country ~ diseases?

Comment: Related: [Effect of foods on diseases](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6500/1652)

Answer (score 2):

Check [health care data sets](https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets#healthcare) from the "Awesome Public Datasets" git repository, and the [FDA](https://open.fda.gov/index.html).

Another possibility is [gapminder](http://www.gapminder.org/data/), which has a subcategory "nutrition" with three data sets (as of this writing). The datasets about disease are much more targeted -- specific subcategories for tuberculosis, cancer, and others -- but there is that kind of data.

The UN FAO also has [an enormous amount of data](http://www.fao.org/economic/ess/en/), although I'm not sure that it counts things at the level of individual health.